# How to read response data from app.use in Node.js and loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I want to read all response data before send.Any possibilities in Node with Loopback.

My code :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //here console log showing [object Object]
  console.log("Reading response data :"+res);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

  if(typeof req.get("content-type") !== 'undefined'){
    res.setHeader('content-type', req.get("content-type"));
  }else{
    res.setHeader('content-type', "text/html;charset=utf-8");  
  }
  next();
});
```

Any possibilities please help me.

Comment: Middleware is called before your response is set.  So 'res' is likely empty or undefined in this context.  What is your use case?  You are supposed to set your response data within a route.

Comment: yeah.Now i used                                                               app.middleware('initial', function logResponse(req, res, next) {
   // install a listener for when the response is finished
   res.on('finish', function() {
     // the request was handled, print the log entry
     console.log(req.method, req.originalUrl, res.statusCode);
     console.log("data"+res);
   });

   // resume the routing pipeline,
   // let other middleware to actually handle the request
   next();
 });

Comment: i want to read response data.

Comment: Try this : console.log(res.render());